# How to call a JavaScript user extension function from Saxon-JS?

Tags: javascript, saxon, extensibility, saxon-js

In Java based Saxon (like 8.1.1 that I am still running after more than a decade) it was super easy to call on your own Java extension functions from within XPath, and moderately easy to build your own extension elements. The documentation had an "Extensibility" section just before "Saxon Extensions". Now in Saxon-JS, I see the "Extensibility" discussion conspicuously absent. Does this mean there is no way to easily call on your own javascript functions from within XPath run by Saxon-JS?

I already imagine a way to work around that ... but I'm weary to say it in fear of Michael Kay shutting that loophole down? I'm going to do it anyway: I think we could use his ixsl extension to drop script elements into a scratchpad area, where they would be executed and leave their result which then would be fetched back. But this seems a rather expensive round-about way of doing it.

Nothing simpler?

Comment: @MichaelKay you were told by that moderator exactly what you need to do: "quote **or summarize** the relevant information from the page you're linking to, in case that page becomes unavailable" (emphasis mine). If you do that, I'm happy to undelete your answer for you; just flag it with a note saying you've fixed the issue. This isn't a theoretical concern, by the way: moderators constantly see questions that don't have useful answers because the linked page changed or went down.

Comment: If the documentation for SaxonJS ever disappears then the product becomes unusable and any precis that appears here becomes useless. The OP here clearly wanted a pointer to the documentation and that's what he's been given.

Comment: Also note, quoting or summarising goes entirely against the DRY principle (don't repeat yourself). It's a bad policy.

Comment: @MichaelKay if you unblock me on Facebook (haha) you can send me the link again there (or here), perhaps make a new answer and I will edit it to be up to the rules, you'd still get the points for the accepted answer and it won't be deleted any more.